# Handling data in inconsistent order for web scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

The following three URL's are an example of data I am trying to scrape. The information is on the left side of the page and includes athletic information along with some other statistics. The data is pulled as one large element. I tried to separate the individual information by index number, but the information is in a different order for each athlete or not available at all. This causes index errors or getting the wrong information all together(i.e. getting 40 yard dash under squat number):

1. https://www.hudl.com/profile/7670389/GaQuincy-McKinstry
   Jersey #: 1
   Positions: CB, WR
   Height & Weight: 6'1" 189lbs
   40 Yard Dash: 4.55
   Bench: 190
   Squat(LBS): 370
   Clean(LBS): 225
   Class of: 2021
2. https://www.hudl.com/profile/10316846/Dylan-Rosiek
   Jersey #: 6
   Positions: MLB, RB
   Height & Weight: 6'1" 210lbs
   Class of: 2021
3. https://www.hudl.com/profile/10015742/Donovan-Jackson
   Jersey #: 77
   Positions: T, G
   Height & Weight: 6'4" 310lbs
   40 Yard Dash: 5.1
   Vertical: 29
   Powerball: 35
   Bench: 365
   Squat(LBS): 415
   Deadlift(LBS): 435
   Class of: 2021

How can I make sure I am writing to the correct columns in my pandas database. Below is the code I attempted for the first URL which is indexed specifically for that page, but will not work on other pages. I temporarily put print functions to see what data I am pulling, but will eventually make a pandas db. I was also unsure if I should grab the information via CSS Selector or Class name.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

TIMEOUT = 5
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)

url = 'https://www.hudl.com/profile/7670389/GaQuincy-McKinstry'
try:
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    pass

time.sleep(3)

try:
    isPresent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button')
    isPresent.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(3)

skills = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#app > div > div.prof-flex-height > div > div > div.parallax-layer.front > div.profile-tab > div > div.left-column > div.stats > ul')
skills = [one.text for one in skills]
print(skills)

try:
    athletic_skills = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stats-list')
    athletic_skills = [skill.text for skill in athletic_skills]
    athletic_skills = athletic_skills[-1].split('\n')
    jersey = athletic_skills[0].replace('Jersey #: ', '')
    position = athletic_skills[1].replace('Positions: ', '')
    height_weight = athletic_skills[2].replace('Height & Weight: ', '')
    height_weight = height_weight.split()
    height = height_weight[0]
    weight = height_weight[-1]
    yard_dash = athletic_skills[3].replace('40 Yard Dash: ', '')
    bench = athletic_skills[4].replace('Bench: ', '')
    squat = athletic_skills[5].replace('Squat(LBS): ', '')
    clean = athletic_skills[6].replace('Clean(LBS): ', '')
    grad_year = athletic_skills[7].replace('Class of: ', '')

    print(athletic_skills)
    print(jersey)
    print(position)
    print(height_weight)
    print(height)
    print(weight)
    print(yard_dash)
    print(bench)
    print(squat)
    print(clean)
    print(grad_year)
except:
    pass

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Load your raw data into a Python dictionary first, for each player.

**Longer answer:**

The dictionary structure allows you to map keys (e.g. `40 Yard Dash`) to the related statistic (e.g. `4.55`).

You can use the data you have already captured in your `athletic_skills` as your starting point.

For example:

```
# new empty dictionary:
mckinstry_skills = {}

for skill_stats in athletic_skills:
    # separate the skill name from the related statistic:
    skill_stats = skill_stats.split(': ', 1) 
    # add this as a new entry into the dictionary:
    mckinstry_skills[skill_stats[0]] = skill_stats[1]

# print the full dictionary:
print(mckinstry_skills)

# print the results of retrieving one item:
print(mckinstry_skills['40 Yard Dash'])
```

The first `print` statement gives this output (formatted by me for clarity):

```
{ 
  'Jersey #'       : '1', 
  'Positions'      : 'CB, WR', 
  'Height & Weight': '6\'1" 189lbs', 
  '40 Yard Dash'   : '4.55', 
  'Bench'          : '190', 
  'Squat(LBS)'     : '370', 
  'Clean(LBS)'     : '225', 
  'Class of'       : '2021'
}
```

The second `print` statement simply returns this:

```
4.55
```

Now you can always reliably get the right statistic for the required pandas column.

Because not all players have all statistics, you may want to make sure that a key exists before trying to get the related statistic:

```
if '40 Yard Dash' in mckinstry_skills:
    print(mckinstry_skills['40 Yard Dash'])
```

If you are not familiar with dicts, there are plenty of overviews available. If you are already familiar, then forgive my over-explanation.